# simplify point geometry

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, point, simplify

I have a great amount of points and I need to show them on map. I am using `OpenLayers`. Is it possible to simplify point geometry in order to speed up the process of rendering?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [OpenLayers Cluster Strategy](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/Cluster-js.html) and related examples:

- [Cluster Strategy Example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/strategy-cluster.html)
- [Cluster Strategy Threshold Example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/strategy-cluster-threshold.html)
- [Extended clustering example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/strategy-cluster-extended.html)

Here's a good tutorial you might be interested in: [Customized OpenLayers cluster strategies](http://openflights.org/blog/2009/10/21/customized-openlayers-cluster-strategies/)

Comment: Are there any other ways how to group point features / just speed up process of rendering?

Answer (score 0):

what is your data type, points, lines, or polygons? The method for simplification and representation would differ depending on this.

Comment: This might have been better posed as a comment on the question, since it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: My data type is: Points

Comment: agreed, however I couldn't see how to comment on the original question.